# find and compress on the fly a file

Tags: bash, find, tar

I'm trying to find and compress on the fly a specific type of the file, but TAR compressed more files than I found.
Fore example:

here I found no.  7

```
 /mnt/1 % find . -name *.pdf
./. /01.pdf
./slide/01.pdf
./slide/03.pdf
./slide/02.pdf
./.Trash-0/files/01.pdf
./.Trash-0/files/01.2.pdf
./.Trash-0/files/01 - Introduzione ISTI + note.pdf
```

but when I compressed on the fly, the archive contain also other files

```
 /mnt/1 % find . -name *.pdf | xargs tar czvf /root/Desktop/evidence/pdf.tar

deft8vm /mnt/1 % tar -tvf /root/Desktop/evidence/pdf.tar 
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2014-04-14 13:51 ././
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2014-04-15 08:27 ././. /
-rw-r--r-- root/root   9070641 2014-04-14 13:40 ././. /01.pdf
drwx------ root/root         0 2014-04-15 08:31 ././. /4Dell/
drwx------ root/root         0 2014-04-15 08:31 ././. /4Dell/4Dell.afd/
-rw-r--r-- root/root   4992592 2014-04-15 08:31 ././. /4Dell/4Dell.afd/file_000.aff.csv
-rw-r--r-- root/root 1051669804 2014-04-15 08:31 ././. /4Dell/4Dell.afd/file_000.aff
-rw-r--r-- root/root       1524 2014-04-15 08:31 ././. /4Dell/4Dell.afd.txt
drwx------ root/root          0 2014-04-14 11:14 ././lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x root/root          0 2014-04-14 13:51 ././slide/
hrw-r--r-- root/root          0 2014-04-14 13:40 ././slide/01.pdf link to ././. /01.pdf

 /mnt/1 % tar -tf /root/Desktop/evidence/pdf.tar | wc -l

29
```

Comment: Specify that you want to `find` _files_: `find . -type f -name "*.pdf" | xargs tar czvf /root/Desktop/evidence/pdf.tar`

Comment: And if `devnull's` example above wasn't clear. You want `find` not the shell to handle `*.pdf`, so you need to quote it (both single and double quotes will work to prevent globbing)

Answer (score 3):

This is why you should never use `find` and `xargs` without `-print0` and `-0` or compatible options.

The filename `./. /01.pdf` is split up into `./.` and `/01.pdf`, and `./.` is equivalent to `.`, i.e. the entire current directory.

There's another, more subtle problem too: `xargs` doesn't run a command with input as parameters. It runs *multiple* commands with *chunks of input* as parameters. This means that if you have enough files, they will be split over multiple tar commands, overwriting each other.

Instead, if you're using GNU, you can use `find -print0` to print `\0` separated filenames, and `tar --null -T` to read them:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -print0 | tar czvf pdf.tar --null -T -
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way of doing this

```
find . -iname "*.pdf" -exec tar --append --file=somefile.tar {} \;
```

Comment: This command generates a .tar but does not compress it. I did something like `find . -iname "*.pdf" -exec tar --append --file=somefile.tar {} \;` and then gzip -9 somefile.tar